# Is there a Tkinter/ttk style reference?

Tags: python, css, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

With `ttk` one can produce code like the following:

```
style.configure('TButton', font='helvetica 24',foreground='red', padding=10)
```

Is there a list of the different options (e.g. font, foreground, padding) and the values (e.g. helvetica 24, red, 10) associated with each of them? I've been searching online and have yet to find such a reference.

Also, is there a css-like thing we can use to style a TKinter GUI? Or is ttk my best bet?

Comment: You could start at Python documentation - [ttkstyling](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html#ttkstyling)

Comment: I thing `ttk` is the only what exists for Tcl/Tk (and Tkinter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most information you should find in [Tk Reference Manual](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tk/). See all widgets and themed widgets.

**EDIT:** maybe more usefull place: [Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-themes.html) on **anzeljg** that now maintains the doc that used to be hosted on the *New Mexico Tech University* website

Comment: This `Tk` reference is not for Python/tkinter specifically, so you should try to improve this answer, because it could be helpful also for other visitors of the website.