# Tkinter ttk see custom theme settings

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

After using `ttk.Style().theme_create('name', settings={})` is it possible to see the settings of that theme?

The reason I'm asking is that when I'm creating a new theme and I add `ttk.Notebook(root)` to my code, the tabs have rounded corners, which I do not want.

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tab Example")
root.geometry('270x270')

background = '#ffffff'
background_dark = '#f2f2f2'

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_create('white', settings={
    'TLabel': {'configure': {'background': background}},
    'TFrame': {'configure': {'background': background}},
    'TNotebook': {
        'configure': {'background': background_dark, 'tabmargins': [0, 7, 2, 0], 'padding': [7, 2]}},
    'TNotebook.Tab': {
        'configure': {'background': background_dark, 'padding': [7, 2], 'focuscolor': 'clear'},
        'map': {'background': [('selected', background)]}}})

style.theme_use('white')

tab = ttk.Notebook(root)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab)

tab.add(tab1, text='Tab 1')
tab.add(tab2, text='Tab 2')
tab.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

ttk.Label(tab1, text="example").pack(padx=36, pady=36)
ttk.Label(tab2, text="example 2").pack(padx=36, pady=36)

root.mainloop()
```

If you remove `style.theme_create()` / `style.theme_use()` then the tabs no longer have rounded corners so the program must be adding that style in by default.

If there isn't a way to see the theme settings (can't seem to find it in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttk-styling)) is there a list of possible settings that I can use? Something specifically for tab borders?

On that note, there's a similar question, [Is there a Tkinter/ttk style reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592132/is-there-a-tkinter-ttk-style-reference) however the first link in the provided answer doesn't list anything for border corners or border styles under [ttk::notebook](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tk/ttk_notebook.html) while the second link is unresponsive.

**EDIT**

Expanding upon Atlas435's answer,

```
style_name = ttk.Notebook(None).winfo_class()
# print(style_name) -> 'TNotebook'

print(style.layout('TNotebook')) # -> [('Notebook.client', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]
print(style.element_options('Notebook.client')) # -> ('borderwidth', 'background')
```

Except for `'background'`, I'm not able to see the names of the custom settings I used above for `'TNotebook'`:

```
style.theme_create('white', settings={
    'TNotebook': {'configure':
        {'background': background_dark, 'tabmargins': [0, 7, 2, 0], 'padding': [7, 2]}}})
```

If I instead do this, I get closer to what I'm looking for but still not quite:

```
print(style.layout('Tab')) # -> [('Notebook.tab', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [('Notebook.padding', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [('Notebook.label', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]})]})]
print(style.element_options('Notebook.tab')) # -> ('borderwidth', 'background')
```

Cycling through the other `element_options` (`Notebook.padding` and `Notebook.label`) doesn't provide the values I'm looking for either :(

**EDIT 2**

Some styling options aren't listed anywhere including the [Tcl/Tk docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_notebook.htm#M38).

An example of this is `'focuscolor'` for `'TNotebook.Tab'` which changes the color of the dashed lines around the Tab when it is in focus.

Another example is when using `ttk.Style().theme_use('default')` or `.theme_use('classic')`, the Tab's in Notebook have rounded edges. If you use `.theme_use('clam')` or `.theme_use('vista')`, the Tab's in Notebook don't have rounded edges.

I'm unable to find that style option in any documentation, and I cannot get it to print through the program (see above **Edit** section).

For now I'm accepting the current best answer (Atlas435) for helping me come to this conclusion.

A temporary solution for anyone else stumbling upon this could be to set either `'clam'` or `'vista'` as a `parent` when using `ttk.Style().theme_create()` or to create a picture that looks like a Tab with the styling you want and use `tab.add(tab1, image=img)`

**FINAL**

A full list is available, check out Atlas 435's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65461962/tkinter-ttk-see-custom-theme-settings/65464537#65464537)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Offical list of all options by ttk

finally found a list that includes all coloration options to style with ttk.
https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Changing+Widget+Colors

---

**ttk.Button**

```
ttk::style configure TButton -background color
ttk::style configure TButton -foreground color
ttk::style configure TButton -font namedfont
ttk::style configure TButton -focuscolor color
ttk::style map TButton -background \
    [list active color disabled color readonly color]
ttk::style map TButton -foreground \
    [list active color disabled color readonly color]

ttk::style configure TButton -bordercolor color
ttk::style configure TButton -lightcolor color
ttk::style configure TButton -darkcolor color
```

**ttk.Checkbutton**

```
ttk::style configure TCheckbutton -background color
ttk::style configure TCheckbutton -foreground color
ttk::style configure TCheckbutton -font namedfont
ttk::style map TCheckbutton -background \
    [list active color disabled color readonly color]
ttk::style map TCheckbutton -foreground \
    [list active color disabled color readonly color]
ttk::style configure TCheckbutton -indicatorcolor color
ttk::style map TCheckbutton -indicatorcolor \
    [list selected color pressed color]
ttk::style configure TCheckbutton -indicatorrelief relief
ttk::style configure TCheckbutton -indicatormargin padding
ttk::style configure TCheckbutton -indicatordiameter size
ttk::style configure TCheckbutton -borderwidth size
ttk::style configure TCheckbutton -focuscolor color
```

**ttk.Combobox**

```
ttk::style configure TCombobox -background color
ttk::style configure TCombobox -foreground color
ttk::style configure TCombobox -fieldbackground color
ttk::style configure TCombobox -darkcolor color
ttk::style configure TCombobox -lightcolor color
ttk::style configure TCombobox -selectbackground color
ttk::style configure TCombobox -selectforeground color
ttk::style configure TCombobox -bordercolor color
ttk::style configure TCombobox -insertcolor color
ttk::style configure TCombobox -insertwidth color
ttk::style configure TCombobox -arrowsize size
ttk::style configure TCombobox -arrowcolor color
ttk::style map TCombobox -background \
    [list disabled color readonly color]
ttk::style map TCombobox -foreground \
    [list disabled color readonly color]
ttk::style map TCombobox -fieldbackground \
    [list disabled color readonly color]
option add *TCombobox*Listbox.background color
option add *TCombobox*Listbox.foreground color
option add *TCombobox*Listbox.selectBackground color
option add *TCombobox*Listbox.selectForeground color
```

**ttk.Entry**

```
ttk::style configure TEntry -background color
ttk::style configure TEntry -foreground color
ttk::style configure TEntry -fieldbackground color
ttk::style configure TEntry -selectbackground color
ttk::style configure TEntry -selectforeground color
ttk::style configure TEntry -bordercolor color
ttk::style configure TEntry -lightcolor color
ttk::style configure TEntry -insertcolor color
ttk::style configure TEntry -insertwidth color
ttk::style map TEntry -background \
    [list disabled color readonly color]
ttk::style map TEntry -foreground \
    [list disabled color readonly color]
ttk::style map TEntry -fieldbackground \
    [list disabled color readonly color]
.entry configure -font namedfont
```

**ttk.Labelframe**

```
ttk::style configure TLabelframe -background color
ttk::style configure TLabelframe -bordercolor color
ttk::style configure TLabelframe -lightcolor color
ttk::style configure TLabelframe -darkcolor color
ttk::style configure TLabelframe.Label -background color
ttk::style configure TLabelframe.Label -foreground color
ttk::style configure TLabelframe.Label -font namedfont
```

**ttk.Listbox**

```
.listbox configure -background color
.listbox configure -foreground color
.listbox configure -disabledforeground color
.listbox configure -selectbackground color
.listbox configure -selectforeground color
.listbox configure -font namedfont
.listbox configure -borderwidth size
.listbox configure -relief relief
.listbox configure -highlightthickness size
.listbox configure -highlightcolor color
.listbox configure -highlightbackground color
```

**menu**

```
.menu configure -background color
.menu configure -foreground color
.menu configure -activebackground color
.menu configure -activeforeground color
.menu configure -disabledforeground color
.menu configure -font namedfont
.menu configure -selectcolor color
.menu configure -activeborderwidth size
.menu configure -relief relief
```

**ttk.Menubutton**

```
ttk::style configure TMenubutton -background color
ttk::style configure TMenubutton -foreground color
ttk::style configure TMenubutton -font namedfont
ttk::style configure TMenubutton -arrowcolor color
ttk::style map TMenubutton -background \
    [list active color disabled color]
ttk::style map TMenubutton -foreground \
    [list active color disabled color]
ttk::style map TMenubutton -arrowcolor \
    [list active color disabled color]
```

**ttk.Notebook**

```
ttk::style configure TNotebook -background color
ttk::style configure TNotebook -bordercolor color
ttk::style configure TNotebook -darkcolor color
ttk::style configure TNotebook -lightcolor color
ttk::style configure TNotebook.Tab -background color
ttk::style configure TNotebook.Tab -foreground color
ttk::style configure TNotebook.Tab -bordercolor color
ttk::style configure TNotebook -focuscolor color
ttk::style configure TNotebook -focusthickness size

ttk::style configure TNotebook.Tab -focuscolor color
ttk::style map TNotebook.Tab -background \
    [list selected color active color disabled color]
ttk::style map TNotebook.Tab -foreground \
    [list selected color active color disabled color]
ttk::style map TNotebook.Tab -lightcolor \
    [list selected color {} color]
ttk::style configure TNotebook.Tab -font namedfont
ttk::style map TNotebook.Tab -font \
    [list selected namedfont active namedfont disabled namedfont]
```

**ttk.Panedwindow**

```
ttk::style configure TPanedwindow -background color

ttk::style configure Sash -sashthickness 5
ttk::style configure Sash -sashrelief relief
ttk::style configure Sash -sashpad 2
ttk::style configure Sash -handlesize 5
ttk::style configure Sash -handlepad 5

ttk::style configure Sash -background color
ttk::style configure Sash -lightcolor color
ttk::style configure Sash -bordercolor color
```

**ttk.Progressbar**

```
ttk::style configure TProgressbar -background color
ttk::style configure TProgressbar -troughcolor color
ttk::style configure TProgressbar -lightcolor color
ttk::style configure TProgressbar -darkcolor color
ttk::style configure TProgressbar -bordercolor color
ttk::style configure TProgressbar -barsize size
ttk::style configure TProgressbar -pbarrelief relief
ttk::style configure TProgressbar -borderwidth size
```

**ttk.radiobutton**

```
ttk::style configure TRadiobutton -background color
ttk::style configure TRadiobutton -foreground color
ttk::style configure TRadiobutton -font namedfont
ttk::style map TRadiobutton -background \
    [list active color disabled color readonly color]
ttk::style map TRadiobutton -foreground \
    [list active color disabled color readonly color]
ttk::style configure TRadiobutton -indicatorcolor color
ttk::style map TRadiobutton -indicatorcolor \
    [list selected color pressed color]
```

**ttk.Scale**

```
ttk::style configure TScale -background color

ttk::style configure TScale -troughcolor color
ttk::style map TScale -background \
    [list active color]
ttk::style configure TScale -troughrelief relief

ttk::style configure TScale -sliderrelief relief
ttk::style configure TScale -sliderlength size
ttk::style configure TScale -sliderthickness size

ttk::style configure TScale -lightcolor color
ttk::style configure TScale -darkcolor color
ttk::style configure TScale -bordercolor color
```

**ttk.Scrollbar**

```
ttk::style configure TScrollbar -background color
ttk::style configure TScrollbar -troughcolor color
ttk::style configure TScrollbar -arrowcolor color
ttk::style configure TScrollbar -bordercolor color
ttk::style configure TScrollbar -darkcolor color
ttk::style configure TScrollbar -lightcolor color
ttk::style configure TScrollbar -sliderrelief relief
ttk::style map TScrollbar -background \
    [list active color disabled color]
ttk::style map TScrollbar -foreground \
    [list active color disabled color]
ttk::style map TScrollbar -arrowcolor \
    [list disabled color]
```

**ttk.Seperator**

```
ttk::style configure TSeparator -background color
```

**ttk.Sizegrip**

```
ttk::style configure TSizegrip -background color
```

**ttk.Spinbox**

```
ttk::style configure TSpinbox -background color
ttk::style configure TSpinbox -foreground color
ttk::style configure TSpinbox -darkcolor color
ttk::style configure TSpinbox -lightcolor color
ttk::style configure TSpinbox -fieldbackground color
ttk::style configure TSpinbox -selectbackground color
ttk::style configure TSpinbox -selectforeground color
ttk::style configure TSpinbox -arrowsize size
ttk::style configure TSpinbox -arrowcolor color
ttk::style configure TSpinbox -bordercolor color
ttk::style configure TSpinbox -insertcolor color
ttk::style configure TSpinbox -insertwidth color
ttk::style map TSpinbox -background \
    [list active color disabled color readonly color]
ttk::style map TSpinbox -foreground \
    [list active color disabled color readonly color]
ttk::style map TSpinbox -fieldbackground \
    [list active color disabled color readonly color]
ttk::style map TScrollbar -arrowcolor \
    [list disabled color]
.spinbox configure -font namedfont
```

**ttk.Text**

```
.text configure -background color
.text configure -foreground color
.text configure -selectforeground color
.text configure -selectbackground color
.text configure -inactiveselectbackground color
.text configure -insertbackground color
.text configure -font namedfont
.text configure -relief relief
.text configure -borderwidth size
.text configure -highlightcolor color
.text configure -highlightthickness size
.text configure -highlightbackground color
```

**ttk.Treeview**

```
ttk::style configure Treeview -background color
ttk::style configure Treeview -foreground color
ttk::style configure Treeview -font namedfont
ttk::style configure Treeview -fieldbackground color
ttk::style map Treeview -background \
    [list selected color]
ttk::style map Treeview -foreground \
    [list selected color]
ttk::style configure Treeview -rowheight [expr {[font metrics namedfont -linespace] + 2}]
ttk::style configure Heading -font namedfont
ttk::style configure Heading -background color
ttk::style configure Heading -foreground color
ttk::style configure Heading -padding padding
ttk::style configure Item -foreground color 
ttk::style configure Item -focuscolor color
```

Comment: I feel like this is in the right direction or maybe this is what I'm looking for but I'm not using it properly? I'm still struggling to get the settings that I was able to modify such as `'TNotebook.Tab': {'configure': { 'focuscolor': 'clear'}}`

Comment: @AndrewStone the code writes a whole new style. You would need to look in the source code for this and check how this *theming engine* works to go deeper. As I said, I'm not a Pro on it. But I think there are some on SO.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'll keep digging and see what I can find

Comment: That list is probably the closest I can get but it's still incomplete, I don't know why it's so hard to find out the settings for rounded corners in Tab's. I discovered `'focuscolor'` from another example somewhere (I forget where I've seen too many to remember specifically) and I can't find that option listed in any doc (including the official link you provided) even though it's a valid setting.

Comment: @Andrew the concept of ttk is to have native looking widgets, this means these aren't meant to be too optional. So I think the theme engine just asks through the xlib for this widgets and doesn't really create them. But that's just guessing. Also note that focus is a standard option, but I couldn't find 'focuscolor' either https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_intro.htm

Comment: That makes sense, I'll have to make do with what I have and hope that they update their docs with all the available settings. I'm going to accept your answer since there isn't anything else to be done here. Thank you for all your help and Happy Holidays!

Comment: @AndrewStone, finally [found it](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Changing+Widget+Colors). Happy Holidays!

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot for finding that list, I wish I could triple upvote you

Comment: Apparently there is no ttk.Text, only tk.Text.