# Is it possible to style a tkinter Text widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk, tkinter-text

I've been using the 'ttkthemes' module to add some additional user-selectable themes to my application via an OptionMenu, and all my Text widgets stand out a bit in their standard style.

I would like to know if it is at all possible to style a Tkinter Text widget with ttk themes.
I know you can't actually style the standard Tkinter widget (you instead must use the respective ttk version).
My issue is that there is no ttk.Text only the entry and I need multiple lines for a text editor.

One possibility would be to change background colour based on the selected theme, but this could be very long since there many themes to choose from.

***Would anyone know of any possible way to get a stylable version of the Tkinter Text widget, so that it doesn't stand out as much?***

Comment: Maybe `Notebook` will help you out [See](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65461962/13629335)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would anyone know of any possible way to get a stylable version of the Tkinter Text widget, so that it doesn't stand out as much?

You can create your own custom `Text` widget that listens to the `<<ThemeChanged>>` event, and then reconfigures itself based on the settings from the current theme or other widgets. For example, you could query the current theme to get the background color of an `Entry` widget and use that to set the background of the `Text` widget.