# Change ttk Entry focus color - Python

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to change the focus color of a `ttk.Entry` widget in python (blue border):

[image]

I know that we can change the focus color of the notebook tabs with `style.configure('Tab', focuscolor='red')`, so I wonder how to do it with an entry widget?

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')
style.configure('TEntry', focuscolor='red') # don't work

ttk.Entry(root).grid(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: if you don't want that , then don't apply any theme

Comment: Same problem with the default macOS theme, and I really want to use a special theme...

Comment: "focuscolor" isn't an option. Try `bordercolor` or `lightcolor` in addition, it is possible you need to use style.map to avoid your color gets changed by default. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65464537/13629335) for a list of opinions available. You may want to take a look on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69890743/13629335) for a brief description of ttk.style, because it may appear that the options you need aren't a choice in the current theme or your system. Also @eshirvana note that there is always a theme set by default.

Comment: @Thingamabobs I already tried the two options, both change the border color of the widget but the focus is still here. I looked at you answers, these are very complet and so you think this is not possible to change my focus color?
PS: I took the `clam` theme for the exemple but in reality I use the `awdark` theme from [awthemes](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/awthemes)

Comment: @MarinNagy these answers are far from complete, I'd tried to cover the important content. See this [tutorial](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-map.html) and try to map the `highlightcolor`. Also note that sometimes features of tk aren't available in ttk. You may end up using a tk.Entry and configure there a highlightcolor.

Comment: Try `style.map('TEntry', lightcolor=[('focus', 'red')])`.

Comment: It works, I didn't know that we can map the `focus` event of a widget for styling. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Thingamabobs and @acw1668 It's possible to change the focus color of a `ttk.Entry` by mapping the focus state in its style property. Here is the working code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')
style.map('TEntry', lightcolor=[('focus', 'white')])

ttk.Entry(root).grid(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

My final goal was to hide the focus border so I changed its color to white (the background color), and now the result looks like this: (The black border is just the original border of the entry)

[image: ttk entry without focus border]