# How to find all style options for ttk widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, ttkthemes

I want to see what all options I can modify on a ttk widget. I used the `style.layout()` method but I am not sure if all the options are being printed. I want to change `ttk.Labelframe` label fg and bg but I can not see any of those options in the `style.layout()` method. I found the answer online, it is done like so: `style.config(TLabelframe.Label, **options)` and it works. But I am curious as to why it doesnt print on my console (obviously nothing wrong with the console, maybe I am not printing the right methods). It works for `TButton` though, exact same print statements. I cant find `TLabelframe.Label` in the prints. Can someone explain me where I am going wrong and how to get all the options I can use for styling a particular widget? Thanks in advance

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from pprint import pprint
from tkinter.font import Font


root = tk.Tk()

lf = ttk.Labelframe(root, text='Labelframe')
btn = ttk.Button(lf, text='Whatever')
btn_font = Font(
    family='Helvetica',
    size=20,
    weight='bold',
    underline=True
)

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure(
    'TButton', font=btn_font,
    foreground='white',
    background='black',
    width=20
)

lf.pack()
btn.pack()

print('----Labelframe----')
print(lf.winfo_class()) 
print(style.layout('TLabelframe'))
print('\nLabelframe.border\n')
print(style.element_options('Labelframe.border'))
print(style.map('TLabelframe'))
print(style.element_options('Labelframe.Label'))

print('----Button----')
print(f'Type:  {type(btn)}')
print(f'Class: {btn.winfo_class()}')
print(f'Layout: {style.layout(btn.winfo_class())}')
btn_label =style.element_options('Button.label')
print(f'Button.label   --->   {btn_label}')
btn_focus = style.element_options('Button.focus')
btn_pad = style.element_options('Button.padding')
btn_border = style.element_options('Button.border')
print(f'Button.focus   --->   {btn_focus}')
print(f'Button.border   --->   {btn_border}')
print(f'Button.padding   --->   {btn_pad}')
print(style.map('TButton'))

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

```
----Labelframe----
TLabelframe
[('Labelframe.border', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]

Labelframe.border

('background', 'borderwidth', 'relief')
{}
()
----Button----
Type:  <class 'tkinter.ttk.Button'>
Class: TButton
Layout: [('Button.border', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'border': '1', 'children': [('Button.focus', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [('Button.padding', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [('Button.label', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]})]})]})]
Button.label   --->   ('compound', 'space', 'text', 'font', 'foreground', 'underline', 'width', 'anchor', 'justify', 'wraplength', 'embossed', 'image', 'stipple', 'background')
Button.focus   --->   ('focuscolor', 'focusthickness')
Button.border   --->   ('background', 'borderwidth', 'relief')
Button.padding   --->   ('padding', 'relief', 'shiftrelief')
{'relief': [('!disabled', 'pressed', 'sunken')]}
```

Comment: For color options you can take a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65464537/13629335)

Comment: @Thingamabobs Thanks a lot! This is what I need. But how do you know all those options exist?

Comment: I searched a while till I found a link. It's in the answer.