# Tkinter differently colored headings

Tags: tkinter, colors

I have a table using multiple headings, i want to be able to change specific headings to specific colors. Is this even possible?

All i've been able to do is change all headings to a single color using `style.theme_use("clam")`

Comment: If you are referring to `ttk.TreeView` then yes, you can change the colors of the heading.

Comment: Like i said, the problem is not changing the color of the heading. The problem is changing specific headings within the same TreeView. First heading is blue next one is green etc.

Comment: No, it is not possible. This option does not exist.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65464537/13629335

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.