# How to apply font defined in JSON file to tkinter ttk Button using a custom theme?

Tags: python, json, tkinter, fonts

I am trying to create a custom theme for my tkinter application using a `JSON` file. I have defined the properties for a ttk `Button` in the `JSON` file, including the font family and size. However, when I apply the theme to my Button, the font is not applied (though the background is).

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```py
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Button, Style
from json import load

root = Tk()
style = Style()

# test.json
"""
{
    "TButton": {
        "configure": {
            "background": "red",
            "font": {
                "family": "Helvetica",
                "size": 20
            }
        }
    }
}
"""

style.theme_create("MyStyle", parent="clam", settings=load(open("test.json")))
style.theme_use("MyStyle")

btn = Button(root, text="Example")
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

As you can see, I'm using the `load()` method from the `JSON` module to load the properties for the `TButton` widget. However, the font is not being applied to the Button.

I've read the documentation on how to use fonts with tkinter [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/font.html#M13) and found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65464537/17053202), but it assumes that a font has been created with the `Font` object, and that it is named. I don't want to have to create a font object in `Python` and then use that name in the `JSON` file (though, even after doing that, it still doesn't work).

How can I define the font in the `JSON` file and apply it to my `ttk` `Button` using a custom theme? I believe there is probably a way to accomplish this with buitlin methods but the documentation on this is very sparse and I have not found anything on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `font` option expects either an instance of `font.Font()` or a string like `"Helvetica 20"` or a tuple/list like `["Helvetica", 20]`, so change `"font"` inside the JSON to:

```
"font": "Helvetica 20"
```

or

```
"font": ["Helvetica", 20]
```

Comment: On a technically seperate but similar note, if I have a font configured already as `Font.NormalFont.TButton`, how could I call that when it was created in a configure? I currently have tried using `"font": "Font.NormalFont.TButton"` but that just gives the `TkDefaultFont` and I'm wondering if that is also possible.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Add `style.theme_create`

> However, when I apply the theme to my Button, the font is not applied
> (though the background is).

In line 22, comment it out as I am not familiar `json`.

Correct way to use `style.theme_create`.

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Button, Style
from json import load

root = Tk()
style = Style()

# test.json
style.theme_create("MyStyle", parent="clam", settings={    
    "TButton": {
        "configure": {
            "background": "red",
            "font": {
                "family": "Helvetica",
                "size": 20
            }
        }
    }
}
) 

#style.theme_create("MyStyle", parent="clam", settings=load(open("test.json")))
style.theme_use("MyStyle")

btn = Button(root, text="Example")
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It still did not apply the font for me.